# ¿que tecnología css están usado?

Tags: css, scss

Buenos días soy relativamente nuevo en esto de la programación. he observado varias webs potentes;  https://ironhack.com o https://thumbtack.com .

En sus css no usan palabras amigables, sino que usan como códigos alfanuméricos tipo encryptados. Alguien sabe que tecnología están usando o plugin para hacer eso con los css? entiendo que es para poner seguridad en tus css no? para que sirve?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del código al que haces referencia en la pregunta? Los enlaces pasado un tiempo podrían dejar de ser accesibles y la pregunta quedaría sin esa información.

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia y no sé si entra bien en el formato/estilo del sitio. Podría deberse a diferentes motivos (encriptacion, generación de identificadores únicos, css-en-js...) y no necesariamente relacionados con la seguridad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que se puede ver en sus repositorios (https://github.com/ironhack) normalmente utilizan sass para los estilos y después los compilan para convertirlos a css y es en ese proceso cuando le pasan un encrypt. Normalmente se hace para que ocupen mucho menos, optimización de performance y tal.

Para el css --> Sass(https://sass-lang.com/) Es lo más extendido en uso, y muy fácil de aprender, te lo recomiendo al 100%.

#### Referencias:

- Sass (https://sass-lang.com/)
- Gulp-Sass para crear las tareas, compilarlo, minificarlo y convertirlo a css (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass)

Comment: Que es el encrypt que mencionas?

Comment: Cuando compilas los SASS para que se conviertan en CSS normalmente aprovechas para minificarlos (y así conseguir que el peso de los archivos sea menor) y con ello muchas veces en ese proceso convierte los nombres de las clases en cadenas alfanumericas de manera que puedan estar no solo minificadas, si no encriptadas.

Comment: Podrías facilitarnos algun minificador que encripte tal como nos has contado? seria de gran ayuda, gracias @JodieHag